# jQuery - Why .att doesn't replace the attribute value?

Tags: jquery

Based on the manual as follows:

```
http://api.jquery.com/attr/ 
attr( attributeName, value )
```

I should be able to replace the attribute value of a selected element.

```
             <div id="keynote1Fld" class="row ">
                <label for="keynote1" class="labeloptional">Topic 1</label>
                <div class="collection">
                 <input type="text" class="largetextfield" maxlength="96" size="96" value="" id="keynote1" name="keynote1" />
                </div>
             </div>
```

I need to replace the class value of label for keynote1 from labeloptional to label.

Here is what have done:

```
$("label[for=keynote1]").att('class', 'label');
```

However, the class value for label of keynote1 still is 'labeloptional' after the execution of the above statement.

why?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `attr` not `att`.

---

However, if you're changing classes, you shouldn't be using `attr()`.

What you should do is use `removeClass()` and `addClass()`.

```
$('label').removeClass('oldClass').addClass('newClass');
```

That way, you won't be overwriting any other classes that might be assigned to a tag.

Comment: More specifically: $('label[for=keynote1]').attr('class', 'label');